# Trying to get a table from a website using Html Agility returns null

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get a table from a website using the Html Agility Pack in C# but it always returns null and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
     var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("some website");
     var htmlBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     var doc = new HtmlDocument();
     doc.LoadHtml(htmlBody);

     var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table");
}
```

I have also tried this XPath but it still doesn't work:

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"__layout\"]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/table");
```

The variable `table` is always null after I run this. Is there something wrong with my code or is it an issue with the XPath I'm using?

Comment: The xpath looks okay. Would probably be more helpful if you could provide a minimal snippet of the HTML that it should've worked on.

Comment: As @NPras pointed, without a concrete example it's very unlikely you will get the help you are looking for.